# How to convert Hex to RGB without using System.Drawing in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, colors, rgb

I'm currently using `System.Drawing` to convert a color HEX code to RGB.

How can I convert it without depending on `System.Drawing`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the libraries that has this functionality is ColorMinePortable. It has no dependencies on `System.Drawing`:

```
using ColorMine.ColorSpaces;

var hex = new Hex("#1d8102");
var rgb = hex.ToRgb();

var red = rgb.R;  // 29
var green = rgb.G; // 129
var blue = rgb.B; // 2
```

Someone forked it an made it available for .NET Standard (and .NET Core) and released it as the Nuget package [ColourMineStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ColorMineStandard/) ([Github](https://github.com/Thraka/ColorMinePortable) fork).